# How to replace pandas dataframe column values based on dictionary key and values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm having a dataframe and a dictionary based on dictionary values that are present in **col1** need to replaced. I tried but it's not changing. What is the efficient way of doing it. Thank You.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 2, 2: np.nan}, 'col1': {0: 'w', 1: 1, 2: 2}})
di = {1: "A", 2: "B"}

df
  col1 col2
0    w    a
1    A    2
2    B  NaN
```

Expected output:

```
df.replace({"col1": di})
  col1 col2
0    w    a
1    1    2
2    2  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `dict` with replace `key` and `value` with each other then use `.replace` as your try:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'w', 1: 'A', 2: 'B'}, 'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 2, 2: np.nan}})
>>> df
    col1    col2
0      w    a
1      A    2
2      B    NaN

>>> di = {1: "A", 2: "B"}
>>> di2 = {v:k for k,v in di.items()}
>>> df.replace({"col1": di2})
    col1    col2
0      w    a
1      1    2
2      2    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just iterate over the dictionary pairs like this:

```
for k, v in di.items()
     df['col1'].replace(k, v, inplace=True)
```